# How do I pass user login name to a function and delete that user from database in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

Here is the code:

```
  create or replace procedure getuser(User_ID In VARCHAR2)Is    
    Username varchar2(30);
    cursor c1(Userid VARCHAR2)  --Cursor o store the row
    IS SELECT USERNAME FROM ALL_USERS WHERE USERNAME = Userid;
    BEGIN
     Open c1(User_id);
     loop
          FETCH c1 INTO USERNAME;
          EXIT WHEN C1%NOTFOUND;
       END LOOP;
       execute immediate 'drop' || USERNAME; 
       CLOSE c1;
    END;
    / 

    execute system.getuser('STUDENT_0602053');
```

the error that am getting is invalid sql statement when i execute the stored procedure
execute system.getuser('STUDENT_0602053');

Comment: Why do you want a function to do this instead of using the `drop user` statement?  Is there going to be a lot of custom logic that isn't in the example code?  Right now the cursor doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop user '||username;
```

You may also want:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop user '||username||' cascade';
```

Or the user won't be dropped if they own any objects.

Also, are you logged in as the user SYSTEM?

Comment: Yes i am logged in as user SYSTEM but it's telling me i don't have the privilege

Answer (score 0):

just a guess - there might be more issues...

but this line needs a space..

```
execute immediate 'drop' || USERNAME;
```

should be

```
execute immediate 'drop ' || USERNAME;
```

Comment: I tried you code but now it's saying i don't have privilege but i am logged in as system

Comment: doh - of course as @DCookie indicates - this is also a DROP USER command - you need that keyword

Comment: ok it worked thanks what i did was put Authid Current_User before the stored procedure so..... create or replace procedure getuser(User_ID In VARCHAR2) Authid Current_User  Is .........